# Merging UVs and textures

Tags: mesh

I have a model that consists of several separate meshes. 
Each mesh has its own UV and texture map.
I would like to merge them and have only 1 UV map and 1 texture map.
Is there a way or a script that would do that painlessly for me?
I have watched videos where this is done with a lot of manual work. I would like to ask if there is an alternative solution, even if it does not use the available space absolutely perfectly.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [Texture Atlas](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/TextureAtlas)

It says it can

> Create one UV Map for all objects (non destructive making)

Which sounds like what you need to do.

As far as combining textures, I think you may have to do that manually. In the future I'd advise you to join your UV's first.

Comment: What do you mean by "join your UV's first"?

Comment: @tmighty Before you paint your texture, to avoid having the merge them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple in Cycles - just assign different materials to different portions of your mesh and use a different UV Map for each. You can have up to 8 UV Maps per mesh object.

I see from the screen shots that you are using Blender Internal though, and I'm not sure if BI supports this.

One thing you can do though, if Texture Atlas doesn't work for you, is lay your images side-by-side in an image editor - not changing the resolution, just ending up with a larger image. So 1024x1024 would become 2048x2048 and you would have 4 textures as one image. Then in the UV/Image Editor scale your UV Map into each of the 4 corners using the 2D Cursor as the scaling Pivot Point. Finally, Join the objects. This should work.